# Change image src via jQuery - don't prompt for download

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have been working on a way to dynamically change the image src on a webpage. I'm using ASP.NET MVC3 and have an image point to a controller action. This works great for first load. Then I have an upload control and refresh the img src via jquery to load the new image. I call the same controller action as before in the first load.

This work in all browsers except for IE. In IE when I change the image and load via jQuery, I get prompted to download the file.

How can I refresh the image and have my required functionality work in IE?

Thanks!

~ Steve

View:

```
 <img src="@Url.Action("ShowSavedImage", "DisplaySettings")" id="imgLogo" class="ContrainImage" />
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult ShowCachedImage()
  {        
    return File(user.TempLogoBytes, user.TempLogoContentType);            
  }
```

JavaScript:

```
 $('#imgLogo').attr('src', '@Url.Content("DisplaySettings/ShowCachedImage/?v=")' + new Date().getTime());
```

Comment: All versions of IE? Are there any reported errors? Is the resultant DOM produced (if you're able to check) by the jQuery the same in IE as in other browsers?

Comment: In other browsers (say chrome) the image just changes as soon as it's src is changed via jQuery. In IE, instead of changing the image, a box pops up asking me to download the file. I can't really see the DOM since it's trying to download the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue wasn't the img src refresh at all. I have a controller action which handles the image save async (from kendoui upload control), and it was returning a JSON result, that was what was popping in the browser. I removed that and all works well.